# Is it possible to create custom buffer like functionality in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I am looking for functionality which can quickly allow me to select a command from a list of commands and paste it to command line. tmux prefix+= provides a buffer from which I can choose and select the copied item however I am  looking for similar way to operate on static list of commands & paste as needed.

testcase:
Once you are in tmux, use shortcut to open command list ( similar to tmux buffer),choose the command, hit enter which should paste it in command line

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to do in regular tmux but luckily there's a mod allowing to do that http://ershov.github.io/tmux/ (I'm the author).

Also, it adds full-fledged scripting support, allows multiple 'mode' commands binding, variables, loops, and so on.

There is an example doing similar thing to what you need in https://github.com/ershov/tmux/blob/master/example_tcl_tmux.tcl :

```
bind H tcl {
    if {[f #{pane_current_command}] eq "bash"} {
        choose-from-list -onselect {
            send-keys $_
        } -- {*}[
            lcomp {$x} for x in [
                split [read_file ~/.bash_history] "\n"
            ] if {[string range $x 0 0] ne "#"}
        ]
        end-of-list
        up
    } else {
        print "Bash?"
    }
}
```

What this binding does is:

1. Reads .bash_history making selection list from it
2. Once selected, sends the string to bash